# CKEditor5 - No Toolbar

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I upgraded my @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react component to the latest version.  I am using a custom editor using the online builder tool.

The editor is displayed successfully and the data content is in the editor.  However, the toolbar is missing.

Is there something different in the new version that we need to enable the toolbar onload??

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation more thoroughly, I found that I had to add the toolbar to the DOM manually.

For reference:
[1]: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/react.html